# Weird DateTime Format Issue With .NET SqlCommand.AddWithValue()

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server

I'm using a parameterized query to read a table:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Now.Date;
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select top 10 * from Mails  where Date>=@today and Date<@tomorrow");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@today", date);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tomorrow", date.AddDays(1));
```

This query was working as expected till the first days of this year. When I checked with SQL Server profiler the query is converted to this format YYYY-MM-DD:

```
select top 10 * from Mails  where Date>='2021-01-05 00:00:00' and Date<'2021-01-06 00:00:00'
```

However, SQL Server seems to expect YYYY-DD-MM for the correct result. This query works as expected:

```
select top 10 * from Mails  where Date>='2021-05-01 00:00:00' and Date<'2021-06-01 00:00:00'
```

The column data type is `DateTime`. As far as I know .NET converts the `DateTime` to the correct SQL format when passed as a parameter. And I haven't experienced such an issue before.

What am I missing?

EDIT 1:

Here is the exact profiler result:

```
exec sp_executesql N'select top 10 * from Mails where Date>=@today and Date<@tomorrow',N'@today datetime,@tomorrow datetime',@today='2021-01-05 00:00:00',@tomorrow='2021-01-06 00:00:00'
```

SQL Server returns us_english to select @@language but the server language and client is tr_turkish.
The format of column is datetime, no issues here. As I said it used to work fine before.

Comment: Just for you: [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: Sounds like caused by a discrepancy in cultures. What are the Windows and SQL languages used ? You're probably using an English (US) SQL Server, and running the application on a machine with a different culture. Am I correct ?

Comment: `DateTime` has no format, it's a binary value. Neither do `datetime`, `datetime2`, `date` or `datetimeoffset` in SQL Server. If you have formatting issues it's because *strings* were used to either store dates or pass date parameters. The solution is to *not* use strings

Comment: I'll add that it is strange that in the profiler you can see STRINGS... I normally see PARAMETERS (and in fact I hate when I have to take a query from the profiler, rebuild the parameters and copy it in the Management Studio to check it)

Comment: Post the `Mails` table schema. I suspect `Date` is a `varchar` column instead of `date`. The real solution is to change the column's type to `date`

Comment: The C# query doesn't match the SQL queries. What you posted wasn't generated by this C# snippet.

Comment: @madreflection No, the approach cmd.Parameters.Add("@today",SqlDbType.DateTime).Value=date; does not work too.

Comment: @aliassce it works. The SQL query you posted doesn't match your code though. `select top 10 * from Mails` became `select * from Mails`. Did you execute older code perhaps? Or used an older SQL trace?

Comment: In any case, what you posted can't be reproduced. There's no way that the query `select top 10 * from Mails  where Date>=@today and Date<@tomorrow` would magically become `select * from Mails  where Date>='2021-01-05 00:00:00' ...`

Comment: @aliassce: That was general guidance, not a direct solution to this problem.

Comment: OK, I changed the tablename and column name which were not English just to keep things easy. The column is datetime no issues here. The exact SQL Profiler result is: exec sp_executesql N'select top 10 * from Mails where Date>=@today and Date<@tomorrow',N'@today datetime,@tomorrow datetime',@today='2021-01-05 00:00:00',@tomorrow='2021-01-06 00:00:00'

Comment: There are no hard-coded date literals in that string. What you assume was a converted format is how the profiler displays the date values. In any case, the ISO8601 format is the only unambiguous date literal format. Is there any actual problem? Or did you assume there may be a problem?

Comment: If you get unexpected results it can be for two reasons only - either there are no matching rows in that range, or the `Date` column is a *text field* with localized data instead of a date-typed field

Comment: Unfortunately, Profiler does its own formatting of parameter values, completely independent of what's actually passed on the wire. Because T-SQL has no separate literal format for `DATETIME`s, it chooses to use an ISO 8601 format, but it uses one that is [not necessarily safe](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/166771/what-date-time-literal-formats-are-language-and-dateformat-safe). This means you cannot copy-paste what Profiler is showing you and expect the same result, but it *also* means your application does *not* have this problem, since it's passing the `DATETIME` as a binary value.

Comment: `The format of column is datetime` that's a type, not a format. You still haven't demonstrated any problem yet. What's the actual problem? Why did you post a question? What made you use the profiler?

Comment: Yes, finally I figured out the issue. After hours of struggling, I feel like silly! My code reads the table that is created by another application. However, that application seems to write wrong dates replacing MM and DD. That application started to enter "2021-05-01" instead of "2021-01-05".  Sorry for taking your time. I think this question needs to be deleted. Thanks everyone especially @PanagiotisKanavos!

Answer (score 1):

Skip the parameters completely:

```
var cmd = new SqlCommand("select top 10 * from Mails  where Date>=cast(cast(current_timestamp as date) as datetime) and Date< cast(dateadd(day, 1, cast(current_timestamp as date)) as datetime)");
```

Once again wishing for the day Sql Server add support for `current_date` like almost every other database. That would save some casting messes.

Comment: Thanks, I figured out that the issue was about wrong data format that was entered by another application.